# How can I write a JavaScript regular expression for 1-4 Roman numerals, 2 Cyrillic letters, and 6 digits?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write a regular expression.
Length > 1 and <= 4 roman numerals, 2 cyrillic letters and 6 digits.

It is necessary to check the correctness of roman numerals.

JavaScript

I found such a proposal, but it is in Perl and does not fully correspond to what I need

```
/^M{0,3}(D?C{0,3}|C[DM])(L?X{0,3}|X[LC])(V?I{0,3}|I[VX])(?<=.)-[А-Я]{2}$/
```

[image]

- XVIАА123456 - true
- IVАЯ123456 - true
- XVIA - false
- XVI - false
- XVIA123456 - false
- XVIAA123 - false

Comment: "does not fully correspond to what I need" - how? Why is it not corresponding to your expectations? Also, please [edit] the question and add examples of valid and invalid inputs (as properly formatted text!)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
^(?=[IVXLCDM]{1,4}[^IVXLCDM])(?:C(?:D|M)|D?C{0,3})(?:X(?:L|C)|L?X{0,3})(?:I(?:V|X)|V?I{0,3})[А-Я]{2}\d{6}$
```

Here:

- `^` beginning of the string,
- `(?=[IVXLCDM]{1,4}[^IVXLCDM])` lookahead to check that begging followed by one to four Roman digits (actual format of roman number before Cyrillic symbols is checked later),
- `(?:C(?:D|M)|D?C{0,3})(?:X(?:L|C)|L?X{0,3})(?:I(?:V|X)|V?I{0,3})` matches roman number. Taken from [here](https://regex101.com/library/zH9eV9),
- `[А-Я]{2}` matches two upper Cyrillic symbols,
- `\d{6}` matches six digits,
- `$` matches end of string.

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/EsPZ9F/3).

Comment: I have already been told how to do it, but thank you for the answer.
My solution: 
/^M{0,3}(D?C{0,3}|C[DM])?(L?X{0,3}|X[LC])?(V?I{0,3}|I[VX])?[А-Я]{2}[0-9]{6}$/

Comment: @NEATweb, regex you mentioned doesn't check for length limit over roman number. Check [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/X3ckej/1)